# how to tell webpack to read images from particular folder without copying into dist ( in development mode)

Tags: webpack

I have images folder parralel to src in 'images' folder and when build done, it is checking into dist only but not outside of it

do how do we tell webpack to read images from images folder in development mode, in production mode I have files on s3 bucket so that is not an issue here.

below is my webpack config file

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

const plugins = require("./webpack.plugin.config");
const modules = require("./webpack.modules.config");

const BUILD_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "dist");

//console.log(process.env.USER);

const isProd = process.env.MODE === "production";

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: ["./src/index.js"],
    draw: ["./src/scripts/draw.js", "./src/styles/draw.css"],
    canvas: ["./src/scripts/canvas.js", "./src/styles/canvas.css"],
    server: ["/src/server/server.js"]
  },
  performance: {
    hints: "warning"
  },
  devServer: {
    static: "./dist",
    open: true,
    hot: true
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: "/public",
    filename: "scripts/[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "scripts/[name].js",
    assetModuleFilename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]",
    clean: true
  },
  mode: process.env.MODE || "none",
  target: "node", // "web"
  node: {
    // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  devtool: isProd ? "source-map" : "eval-source-map",
  watch: !isProd,
  plugins,
  module: modules,
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".html", ".js", ".json", ".css"]
  },
  ...(isProd && {
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin()]
    }
  })
};
```

and here is folder structure under *src*

```
| src
├───assets
│   ├───fonts
│   │       AnandaBlackPersonalUseRegular-rg9Rx.ttf
│   ├───images
│   │   ├───background
│   │   │       apple.jpg
│   │   │       blank.jpg
│   │   │       cat.jpg
│   │   │
│   │
│   └───screenshots
│           canvas.png
│           index.png
├───common
│       constants.js
│       helper.js
│       utils.js
│
├───html
│       about.html
│       canvas.html
│       draw.html
│       index.html
│
├───mappers
│       alphabet.js
│
├───scripts
│       canvas.js
│       draw.js
│
├───server
│       server.js
│
└───styles
        base.css
        canvas.css
        draw.css
        index.css
```

Answer (score -2):

To configure Webpack to read images from a specific folder without copying them into the dist directory during development mode, you can use the **file-loader** or **url-loader** to handle image files. Here's how you can modify your webpack configuration to achieve this:

1. Install the necessary loader packages if you haven't already:

   `npm install file-loader --save-dev`
2. Update your `webpack.config.js`:

`

```
const plugins = require("./webpack.plugin.config");
const modules = require("./webpack.modules.config");

const BUILD_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "dist");
const SERVER_FILE = path.join(process.cwd(), "/src/server/server.js");

const isProd = process.env.MODE === "production";

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: ["./src/index.js"],
    draw: ["./src/scripts/draw.js", "./src/styles/draw.css"],
    varnmala: ["./src/scripts/varnmala.js", "./src/styles/varnmala.css"],
    canvas: ["./src/scripts/canvas.js", "./src/styles/canvas.css"],
    server: [SERVER_FILE]
  },
  performance: {
    hints: "warning"
  },
  devServer: {
    static: "./dist",
    open: true,
    hot: true
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: "/public",
    filename: "scripts/[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "scripts/[name].js",
    assetModuleFilename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]",
    clean: true
  },
  mode: process.env.MODE || "none",
  target: "node", // "web"
  node: {
    // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
    __dirname: false, // if you don't put this is, __dirname and __filename return blank or /
    __filename: false
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  devtool: isProd ? "source-map" : "eval-source-map",
  watch: !isProd,
  plugins,
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...modules.rules, // Your existing rules
      
      // Add this rule for images
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/images'), // Point to your images folder
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images', // Place images in this directory within dist
              publicPath: '/public/images', // Adjust the public path as needed
              emitFile: false, // Do not emit the file to the output directory
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".html", ".js", ".json", ".css"]
  },
  ...(isProd && {
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin()]
    }
  })
};
```

In this configuration:

We're using the file-loader to handle image files.

- The `include` option ensures that the loader only processes files
  within the specified folder.
- `outputPath` determines where the images should be placed within the
  dist directory.
- `publicPath` specifies the public URL path to the images.
- `emitFile: false` prevents the loader from emitting the file to the
  output directory, which is necessary to avoid copying the images.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so you are suggesting that I need to copy images in *dist* folder? I have also updated question with my folder structure, can you now suggest proper way becaue the mosut confusing is publicpath and outputPath

Comment: No. Actually we've put the `emitFile:false` property to false which prevents the images from being copied into dist.  So if your images are placed in the `/src/assets/images` directory, the possible makup will look like

  `<!-- Reference to an image using its name --> `
  `<img src="/assets/images/background/apple.jpg" alt="Apple Image">`

Could you confirm that are you doing the same it before like above?

Comment: not working. can you please try it yourself on [this branch](https://github.com/xkeshav/canvas/tree/feature/refactor)

Comment: for testing purpose, added snippet in html/index.html

Comment: sure let me see it.

Comment: @xkeshav, what command you're using to run code in development mode? I"m running `npm run client:local` for compiling. And I see there're no images folder in the dist. The only hurdle which I see is how to serve images from the `src/assets/images` directory.

Comment: do not run `client: local` but just `npm run client`.

Comment: and I do not want to copy images flder in *dist* , and the hurdle you are facing is the exact my porblem is.

Comment: "do not run `client:local` but just `npm run client`". It will run the webpack in production mode as per your package.json settings. We've to run the `client:local` or make an other way to run the webpack in development mode.